# XmlSerializer - Combining multiple elements into a list which all have the same signature but different tag names

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm still pretty fresh to C# and XML so excuse me if I use the wrong terminology.

I'm trying to serialize an XML string into a class I'm building. The problem is, one of the elements contains a "list" of elements that all have the same structure, but they each have a different tag name...like so:

```xml
<Results>
  <factors>
    <factor1 code="012">Some text</factor1>
    <factor2 code="123">Some text</factor2>
    <factor3 code="234">Some text</factor3>
    <factor4 code="345">Some text</factor4>
    <factor5 code="456">Some text</factor5>
  </factors>
</Results>
```

I've built a class like this:

```cs
public class Factor
{
  [XmlAttribute("code")]
  public string Code { get; set; }
  [XmlText]
  public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Factors
{
  [XmlElement("factor1")]
  public Factor Factor1 { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("factor2")]
  public Factor Factor2 { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("factor3")]
  public Factor Factor3 { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("factor4")]
  public Factor Factor4 { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("factor5")]
  public Factor Factor5 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Results")]
public class Results
{
  [XmlElement("factors")]
  public Factors Factors { get; set; }
}
```

Since in this case, Factor1-5 all have the same "shape", is there a way for me to read these into a list instead?

This isn't something I absolutely need to figure out, but I was curious to see if there was a simple solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size. If you don't need to re-serialize the objects, this will deserialize your example XML in (note the added `ElementName` on `Factor` if you need to know what the actual element name was. Otherwise, discard it from the class and code).

```
public class Factor
{
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Results")]
public class Results : IXmlSerializable
{
    public Factor[] Factors { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) => this.Factors = XDocument
        .Load(reader.ReadSubtree())
        .Descendants("factors")
        .Descendants()
        .Select(factorElement => new Factor
        {
            ElementName = factorElement.Name.ToString(),
            Code = (string)factorElement.Attribute("code"),
            Text = factorElement.Value
        })
        .ToArray();

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```